# jQuery hide IE mess up

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, show-hide

Could anyone let me know why the hide and show boxes are playing up when you click contact?

They only do this in IE. I cannot seem to fix the problem.

This is the website: http://molossi.psm2.co.uk/

Thanks :)

EDIT: [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTTRF.png) is a picture of on of the issues on IE.This is taken after I have clicked Contact then Cancel. I have zoomed out to 75% to capture more.

Comment: @hart1994 Its working for me in chrome, Firefox

Comment: Are you looking for the code snippets responsible for this behavior?

Comment: @Mithun P Chrome my work - but the OP mentions IE!

Comment: @Mithum P, it is messing up in Internet Explorer. And yes I am + a possible solution.

Comment: I have only tested the website in IE 8.

Comment: @hart1994 describe what is exactly messing up, (a screenshot will be helpful in understanding the problem..)

Comment: Can't you test it? And I have included an image now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working fine for me when I tested the link in IE...I think this css is causing the problem:

```
/*Win IE browsers - hide from Mac IE\*/
* html #main-nav { margin-top:20px; }
* html #main-nav li { display:inline; float:left; }
/*End hide*/
```

When you click on contact it shows a div below the navigation-bar and when you cancel it loads a separate div outside of navigation-bar div. So in your browser somehow the switching among nav-bar and outside div is not happening as it should be.

Try to concentrate on main-nav property of the css. Maybe line-height or margin-top or height is causing this.

Comment: I have removed this and it isn't any different. I can't seem to find anything wrong with that bit of code :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a doctype in order to use Standards Mode and you should validate your HTML and CSS:

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmolossi.psm2.co.uk%2F

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?profile=css21&warning=0&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmolossi.psm2.co.uk%2F

Comment: So if I add the doc type it will fix these issues?

Comment: Possibly. Right now you are "letting" IE "emulate" the errors of older browsers. Even if it doesn't directly correct the problem, it will be much easier to do so.

Comment: Ok thank you, I am still currently working to correct the issues I am having.